# Ignore newline before \end of environment

Tags: environments

How do I ignore newlines at the end of a custom environment?

```
\newenvironment{sentence}
  {}
  {.}


\begin{sentence}
This is a sentence


\end{sentence}
```

The output is

```
This is a sentence
.
```

And I would like

```
This is a sentence.
```

Comment: ignoring one is easy (as that's just a space) ignoring two (end of paragraph) is harder unless you are prepared to grab the whole content in advance (which means you can't use `\verb` and other special catcode based commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple and effective but it disables all paragraphs in the environment, not just the final one. Given that the environment is `sentence` perhaps that is OK.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{sentence}
  {\let\par\relax}
  {\ifhmode\unskip\fi.\endgraf}

\begin{document}



\begin{sentence}This 1 is a sentence\end{sentence}

\begin{sentence}
This 2 is a sentence
\end{sentence}

\begin{sentence}
This 3 is a sentence

\end{sentence}


\end{document}
```

---

A slightly more fragile version that allows multiple paragraphs

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{sentence}
  {\def\par{\futurelet\tmp\zzpar}}
  {\ifhmode\unskip\fi.\endgraf}

\def\zzpar{%
 \ifx\tmp\par\else
  \ifx\tmp\end\else
    \endgraf
  \fi\fi}

\begin{document}



\begin{sentence}This 1 is a sentence\end{sentence}

\begin{sentence}
This 2 is a sentence
\end{sentence}

\begin{sentence}
This 3 is a sentence

\end{sentence}

\begin{sentence}
This 4a is a first paragraph.

This 4b is a second


\end{sentence}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as you suspected I am looking for a solution that only removes the last linebreak (if it exists)

Comment: @Matthias as I say that really isn't possible in full generality so it would be better to give some more examples (preferably as complete test documents, as here) in your question. but I'll add a version...

Comment: Wow this is really cool, thank you! I need this to add a \strut at the end of the content of a tcolorbox (without creating an artificial newline if the box ends with one). But I could see it being used for an automatic \qedhere as well. Since you say it is not possible in full generality, where do you see the limitations of this approach?

Comment: @Matthias well for example this assumes when you get to `\end` then you have got to the end but that doesn't consider nested environments, what you do in nested environemnts depends on what you want to do, and getting a full spec for that is tricky. When it works it works but changing the meaning of `\par` will break something, hard to say what but I wouldn't take a bet on this working with any arbitrary package code you find on ctan or this site. If it breaks, I just want to say "I told you so" rather than be blamed for it breaking:-)

Comment: Yeah I see. Thanks! :)